# fatal error all goroutines are asleep deadlock

Tags: go

Can you explain the following error: fatal error: 

true

true

all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func printer(ch chan bool) {
    ch <- true
}

func main() {
    var c chan bool = make(chan bool, 2)

    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        go printer(c)
    }

    for i := range c {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get the same output. On 1.5.2 it prints as expected - five "true" lines and then it deadlocks because channel is not being closed and range loop just waits forever

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the channel `c` is not closed, the range loop does not exit.  This code will not block:

```
func main() {
  var c chan bool = make(chan bool, 2)

  for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
    go printer(c)
  }

  for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
    fmt.Println(<-c)
  }
}
```

<kbd>[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/DurYw16O2j)</kbd>

Comment: Why range does not stop automatically?

Comment: @inanc Range stops when the channel is closed. Otherwise, it blocks waiting for values.