# all goroutines are asleep in my async code

Tags: go

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34572122/fatal-error-all-goroutines-are-asleep-deadlock) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12398359/throw-all-goroutines-are-asleep-deadlock) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41653695/all-goroutines-are-asleep-deadlock) but none of them solving my issue..

I'm trying to read 2 files async, so I wrote the below:

```golang
//readlines.go
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "os"
)

// readLines reads a whole file into memory
// and returns a slice of its lines.
func readLines(path string) ([]string, error) {
    file, err := os.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer file.Close()

    var lines []string
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        lines = append(lines, scanner.Text())
    }
    return lines, scanner.Err()
}
```

And calling it as:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/gocarina/gocsv"
)

func (s *stocks) Read() {
    fmt.Println("Reading")
    stockFile, err := os.OpenFile("current_invenory.csv", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE, os.ModePerm)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer stockFile.Close()
    stocks := []systemStock{}
    if err := gocsv.UnmarshalFile(stockFile, &stocks); err != nil { // Load stocks from file
        panic(err)
    }

    *s = stocks
}

package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/gocarina/gocsv"
)

func (t *transactions) Read() {
    fmt.Println("Reading")
    trxFile, err := os.OpenFile("current_transactions.csv", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE, os.ModePerm)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer trxFile.Close()
    trx := []systemTransactions{}
    if err := gocsv.UnmarshalFile(trxFile, &trx); err != nil { // Load stocks from file
        panic(err)
    }

    *t = trx
}
```

The above working very fine with:

```golang
    stock := stocks{} 
    trx := transactions{}

    stock.Read()
    trx.Read()
    for _, s := range stock {
            fmt.Println("Hello", s.Code)
    }
```

But give the error `fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!` when I tried to read them as:

```golang
    cs, ct := readData()

    for _, s := range cs {
        fmt.Println("Hello", s.Code)
    }

    for _, t := range ct {
        fmt.Println("Hello trx of ", t.Code)
    }
```

Using

```golang
import "sync"

//func readData(cs chan stocks, ct chan transactions) (stocks, transactions) {
func readData() (stocks, transactions) {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    defer wg.Done()

    stock := stocks{}
    trx := transactions{}

    wg.Add(1)
    go stock.Read()
    wg.Add(1)
    go trx.Read()

    wg.Wait()

    return stock, trx
}
```

So the error is related for something wrong I made (or do not understand) in the last block~

Comment: Your code does not run `wg.Done()` twice (or even once), so it blocks forever on `wg.Wait()`

Comment: @zerkms any idea how to get it done correctly?

Comment: You could pass a pointer to `wg` to each of your goroutines and `Done` it as long as you're done with them

Comment: This would be a much clearer question if you had simply included a minimal, verifiable code example and its output.  All these snippets of code just make it confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run the `Read` methods for `stocks` and `transactions` concurrently, these methods need to have a way of signaling when they are finished executing. This can be done in a lot of ways, but here are two which require the least modifications to your code.

**Solution 1**

Use the `sync.WaitGroup` package. With this package, the `Read` methods should execute `wg.Done()` statement when they are done with executing. It should look something like this:

```
func (s *stocks) Read(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    fmt.Println("Reading")
    stockFile, err := os.OpenFile("current_invenory.csv", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE, os.ModePerm)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer stockFile.Close()
    stocks := []systemStock{}
    if err := gocsv.UnmarshalFile(stockFile, &stocks); err != nil { // Load stocks from file
        panic(err)
    }

    *s = stocks
}

func (t *transactions) Read(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    fmt.Println("Reading")
    trxFile, err := os.OpenFile("current_transactions.csv", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE, os.ModePerm)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer trxFile.Close()
    trx := []systemTransactions{}
    if err := gocsv.UnmarshalFile(trxFile, &trx); err != nil { // Load stocks from file
        panic(err)
    }

    *t = trx
}

func readData() (stocks, transactions) {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)

    stock := stocks{}
    trx := transactions{}

    go stock.Read(&wg)
    go trx.Read(&wg)

    wg.Wait()

    return stock, trx
}
```

**Solution 2**

This approach uses the `golang.org/x/sync/errgroup` package. In this case, you do not need to handle the synchronization and signaling yourself, but functions that are added with `errgroup.Go` method need to have a strict `func() error` signature. Your code should look like this:

```
func (s *stocks) Read() error {
        fmt.Println("Reading")
        stockFile, err := os.OpenFile("current_invenory.csv", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE, os.ModePerm)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        defer stockFile.Close()
        stocks := []systemStock{}
        if err := gocsv.UnmarshalFile(stockFile, &stocks); err != nil { // Load stocks from file
            return err
        }
    
        *s = stocks
        return nil
    }
    
    func (t *transactions) Read() error {
        fmt.Println("Reading")
        trxFile, err := os.OpenFile("current_transactions.csv", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE, os.ModePerm)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        defer trxFile.Close()
        trx := []systemTransactions{}
        if err := gocsv.UnmarshalFile(trxFile, &trx); err != nil { // Load stocks from file
            return err
        }
    
        *t = trx
        return nil
    }
    
    func readData() (stocks, transactions) {
        g, _ := errgroup.WithContext(context.Background())
    
        stock := stocks{}
        trx := transactions{}
    
        g.Go(stock.Read)
        g.Go(trx.Read)
    
        if err:= g.Wait(); err != nil {
           panic(err)
        }
    
        return stock, trx
    }
```

**Solution 3**

You’re (correctly) adding 1 to the wait group when you start reading from each CSV, bringing the wait group’s internal counter to 2, but wg.Wait() will wait until that counter goes down to zero and you don’t have any calls to wg.Done() to do that. I recommend changing go stock.Read() to:

```golang
go func() {
    defer wg Done()
    stock.Read()
}()
```

So, the full working code be:

```golang
func readData() (stocks, transactions) {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    stock := stocks{}
    trx := transactions{}

    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        stock.Read()
    }()
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        trx.Read()
    }()

    wg.Wait()

    return stock, trx
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I liked option 2, as it gives me the freedom to use `func (t *transactions) Read()` or `func (s *stocks) Read()` alone if i want, without using `sync.WaitGroup` if they are called as individuals

Comment: I found another solution at `Go Forum` so added to the same answer as solution 3 :) https://forum.golangbridge.org/t/all-goroutines-are-asleep-deadlock/21162